# Performance test IIS 8 response time very low, is there any configuration necessary?

Tags: performance

I have been running performance tests on an asp.net mvc 4 application  using visual studio 2012 ultimate, the response and the pages per second have been quite high at least when I ran the performance tests with IIS express as the server, but I moved the application to IIS 8
and the pages per second have been very low, never exceeding 1.x even with very low numbers of virtual users. there any configuration changes I need to apply on IIS?

Output caching and Kernel model caching are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout official Microsoft tips and solutions on improving IIS performance:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050.aspx